# ADF / Convert csv table to json

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm working on Azure Data Factory (I'm the beginner of it).
I've assigned with the task where I've to convert the table(csv file) in JSON. I've started it by using Azure Mapping Flow. I get data from csv file as a source and transfer that data using pivot. After the pivot, I'm not able to find appropriate output plus the sink json is generating multiple json files.

Here is my sample input data:

[image]

I want output as below:

```
[
    {
        "Article": "A1",
        "Catalog": "C2",
        "GlobalCatalog": "C1",
        "CatalogSegmentation": [
            "S1"
        ],
        "GlobalSegmentation": [
            "S1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Article": "A2",
        "Catalog": "C2",
        "GlobalCatalog": "C1",
        "CatalogSegmentation": [
            "S1"
        ],
        "GlobalSegmentation": [
            "S1",
            "S2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Article": "A1",
        "Catalog": "C3",
        "GlobalCatalog": "C1",
        "CatalogSegmentation": [],
        "GlobalSegmentation": [
            "S1"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Article": "A2",
        "Catalog": "C3",
        "GlobalCatalog": "C1",
        "CatalogSegmentation": [
            "S2"
        ],
        "GlobalSegmentation": [
            "S1",
            "S2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Any regulation here? Can't configure it out.. please give more clarification.

Comment: hi,you need any assistance here? Would you please give more details? Or you already have got the solution?